# Minimum set of comparing operators to override

Tags: python, operators, overriding

I would like to override all comparing operators (==, !=, <, <=, >, >=) in Python and I would like to do the least I can. In logic point of view it is enough to define two any operators (excluding pairs: == and !=, < and >=, > and <=). What is the minimum set of these operators to override in Python? Is it for example enough?

```
class MyInt:
    __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num == other.num
    __lt__(self, other):
        return self.num < other.num
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply the [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator to your class. From its docs:

> The class must define one of `__lt__()`, `__le__()`, `__gt__()`, or
>   `__ge__()`. In addition, the class should supply an `__eq__()` method.